# chart not display inside a bootstrap-modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to show a chart in a bootstrap modal. Codes here:
  but it doesn't work, chart not display. How to fix that?

---

```
<div id="myModel" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div id="chart1" style="height:300px; width:600px;"></div>

</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

---

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1=[['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5], ['25-Jul-08', 480.88], ['22-Aug-08', 509.84];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
      title:'Data Point Highlighting',
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
          } 
        },
        yaxis:{
          tickOptions:{
            formatString:'$%.2f'
            }
        }
  });
  $('#myModal').bind('shown',function() {
    plot1.replot();
  });
});
</script>
```

---

#button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModel">Draw

Comment: Could you please add this into a JS fiddle so that I can change it around?

Answer (score 11):

you must show char after showing compelete modal box

In bootstrap 3 :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
    title:'Data Point Highlighting',
    axes:{
      xaxis:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{
          formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
        } 
      },
      yaxis:{
        tickOptions:{
          formatString:'$%.2f'
        }
      }
    });              
});
```

Answer (score 4):

try draw chart after modal like this:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
// and then
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  plot1.replot();
  //...
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very dated question, however I ran into a similar issue recently using react, react-bootstrap and chartjs - never had an issue until attempting to render a chart within a modal. If you're having a similar issue and are using react with bootstrap and the react-bootstrap library, there is an `onEntered` event one can use. For my scenario, conditionally rendering the chart, using state that is updated when the callback for `isEntered` is invoked, solved the problem nicely.

If a code snippet would help anyone, please lmk.

Docs for react-bootstrap component library modal:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#api